# Does the phrase "it seems to me" without any complement mean something?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Let's look at the first verse of Sweet Child of Mine:

> She's got a smile that it seems to me

does that verse have a complete meaning on its own?

We can also look at Motorhead's "I Don't Believe a Word":

> Don't talk of love, it seems to me
>
> all the people that we rob, sometimes I think of how they used me

those songs give me the impression that the sentence "it seems to me" has a meaning of its own. Am I wrong?

Comment: You need to understand that for reasons of rhythm, poems and song lyrics are arranged into lines, but you need to read more than one line to see the meaning _She's got a smile that **it seems, to me / Reminds me of childhood memories / Where everything was as fresh as the bright blue sky**._

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't know, those constructions are pretty weird and both have the "it seems to me"

Comment: it seems to me [that] all the people that we rob, sometimes I think of how they used me

Comment: Anyhow, song words don't have to make sense.

Comment: @hellofriends  What is it exactly that seems weird to you?  You have to be more specific than that.

Comment: @stangdon well, I think it is pretty obvious. But sure. In Motorhead's example "sometimes" starts a new sentence and the previous sentence is litteraly "it seems to me all the people that we rob" which I can't grasp the meaning of.

Comment: 'Sometimes' doesn't start a new sentence.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it does.

Comment: Where are the period and following capital letter? Sometimes starts a _clause_.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey we have two clauses after "it seems to me". I think that is very weird. "I seems to me the sky is blue, Mary went home"

Comment: hellofriends - I repeat. _It's a song_. It is OK, even normal, if they don't make literal sense. Or any sense. It could be 'I seems to me the sky is blue, I want to give a dog to you' and it wouldn't matter. Yoiu hear the tune, you tap your feet, you go 'Tra-la-la', or, in this case, play air guitar. Don't over think it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It seems to me" can be used in various ways in English. "It seems to me" can be used as  parenthetical, functioning similarly to an adverb like "apparently": "Cheese, it seems to me, is the finest food." "Going home now is the best choice, it seems to me." Here it's an additional comment by the speaker on the truth of the sentence: you can use other phrases like "I guess", or "I think" in a similar fashion.

It can also introduce a clause describing what appears to be true: here the structure is "it seems" + indirect object ("to me") + clause. The clause can be introduced by "that" or not. See for instance [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/it-seems) with examples including "It seems to me this is his most important novel." Another example of this would be "It seems to me that Madonna is the greatest pop star of the 20th century" or equally "It seems to me Madonna is the greatest pop star of the 20th century." In this case you could substitute "appears" or something similar in place of "seems". "It" is a dummy pronoun in this construction: the actual subject is the clause at the end, which does the seeming, but this is a common construction in English.

In the Guns 'n' Roses song, "She's got a smile that it seems to me / Reminds me of childhood memories" you could remove "it seems to me" without changing the meaning; this is a parenthetical usage. (It is probably redundant, because "reminds" includes the sense of "it seems to me", but rock lyrics often include redundancies for the purpose or rhyme or fitting the tune).

I'm slightly at a loss how to parse the Motorhead song: "Don't talk of love, it seems to me / All the people that we rob / Sometimes I think of how they used me". I don't think "it seems to me" has much meaning here, other than to emphasise the subjective impressions (also mentioned in "I think") - indicating this is a personal view.

So in both songs "it seems to me" don't have a particular contribution to the meaning of the lyrics. It emphasises that something is an impression or subjective valuation. You probably don't want to use it as carelessly as this in your daily life (unless you need a rhyme).